# Why different customs for daily and Shabbat Kedusha?

Tags: shabbat, chol-weekday, kedusha-prayer

In the repetition of the Shabbat amida, we who are not leading say all lines of the Kedusha, as does the shaliach tzibur.

In the repetition of the daily amida, only the shaliach says all the sentences of the Kedusha. We who are not leading say only the 3 main sentences.

What is the logic behind this?

(I have heard there are other customs, less often followed. Perhaps that is key to the answer.)

Related: [Why is it common practice to say Nakdishach/Nekadesh before the hazzan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53681/why-is-it-common-practice-to-say-nakdishach-nekadesh-before-the-hazzan?rq=1)

Comment: Who's "we"? This is not _my_ custom.

Comment: @DoubleAA  We refers to every siddur I have checked (although not all have directions concerning this).  In any case, what is your minhag (custom)?  Do you know from whence it derives?

Comment: I haven't encountered the practice you describe. There's one opinion that the congregation only says the lines "kadosh", "barukh", and "yimklokh". There's another opinion that they say everything. But there's no distinction between Shabbat and weekday in either position.

Comment: @paquda  You may see it in any Art Scroll siddur: compare the Kedusha instructions for the daily and Shabbat services that have a repetition.

Answer (score 1):

In the weekday the Shliach Tzibur leads with leading phrases, לעמתם משבחים ואומרים, facing them [the other angels] praise and they say, and ובדברי קדשך כתוב לאמר, and in the words of your holy ones it is written. These phrases are preparations for the coming sentence. Since these are merely leading into the next stanza some have the Minhag that only the Shliach Tzibur says it.

However, in all Minhagim the whole congregation says וקרא זה אל זה ואמר in the first piece although it is of the same nature. This is because we are already saying everything until there. It flows with the rest of נקדישך.

On Shabbos, when we have a more elaborate Kedusha which expounds on the statements. Once we are already saying everything until לעמתם we don't leave it out since it flows with it as well.

Comment: Who's "we"? This is not _my_ custom. Why is everyone in this rite saying the bit before לעמתם at all?

Comment: @DoubleAA I only used "we" where all Minhagim converge. We all say the first. You already voiced your issue with the question, but I came to answer the question, not clarify it. As I stated, on Shabbos we have an elaborate Kedusha. It is not just leading words, it is expounding on what we've said.

Comment: What do you mean we all say the first? The first what? Does an unclear question require an unclear answer? Why couldn't you just use descriptive words to clarify what groups you referred to, even if the OP was lax on that?

Comment: It's simply not true that in all Minhagim the whole congregation says וקרא זה אל זה. In fact 600 years ago it was virtually unheard of.

Comment: @DoubleAA Seems like they didn't say נקדישך/נעריצך either. My point is that once your are saying the rest we finish off with the leading words too, as we do in the rest of Tefilla.