# When does Kedusha start?

Tags: tefilla, standing-sitting, kedusha-prayer

During [Kedusha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5708/moving-from-ones-spot-after-kedusha), one is to stand with the proper physical attitude (or, if one is still davening, stop and listen, at least according to some opinions). But when does Kedusha begin? Knowing when it actually "starts" would affect someone who is walking in, or someone who is still davening his own Amida and has to know when to pause.

Does it begin when the chazzan finishes the bracha of mechayei hameitim? Does it begin when the Chazzan (after waiting for the kahal to say the opening words) begins saying "Nekadesh"/"Na'aritz'cha"/"Na'aritzach"? On the Yamim Nora'im, is it when we get to "[Keter yitnu](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16079&st=&pgnum=449)"? I have even heard that it only really starts when someone says "Kadosh, kadosh, kadosh" -- but I don't know if that refers to the Kahal or the Chazzan.

Comment: There's no need to do anything before the Chazzan starts http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53688/759

Comment: I'm not aware of a fundamental need (ignoring any arbitrary local custom) to keep feet together except while saying "Kadosh...Kevodo" and "Barukh...Mimmekomo" (and maybe "Yimlokh...Halleluyah") https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%9F/%D7%90/%D7%9B%D7%97

Comment: @DoubleAA wrote what I would have. Although Qedushah is the name of the whole berakhah, and there is "an inyan" (meaning, some like to be machmir) to stand that way until after "HaKeil haQadosh." "Amein."

Comment: Re the opening words - I believe those are the sh'li'ach tzibur's introduction to the rest of the daveners, which was, over time, assimilated into the tzibur's lines out of zeal. Along those lines, "k(i)dusha" that we recite thrice daily is essentially the three p'sukim, not the translation, elaboration, commentary that attends it. Also, the Chayei Adam may be one source who recommends staying with one's feet together until the end of the ברכה, but it wasn't clear to me when I read it and don't have a copy at the moment.